# Error while running oracleProc function in R

Tags: r, roracle

I am trying to call oracle procedure from R using oracleProc method in ROracle library and getting the below error:

**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘oracleProc’ for signature ‘"OraConnection", "function"’**

Does this mean that oracleProc function has not been implemented in ROracle yet ? I am using ROracle Version 1.3-1

Answer (score 0):

i was able to use oracleProc by passing sql statement rather than procedure in its parameter.

stmt <- paste("Begin proc(:1,:2,:3);End;")

oracleProc(con,stmt,df)